# How to limit the no of pairs in single record while using a reducebykey

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My input as below.

Input:

```
key,A,1
key,A,2
key,A,3
key,A,4
key,A,5
key,A,6
```

I am using the below code to achieve my first output

```
val finalOutputRDD = AddDeletesRDD.map(x => ( x.split("~").slice(0, endOfKeyPosition).mkString(","), x.split("~").slice(0, 1).mkString(",") + "~" + x.split("~").slice(3, 4).mkString(",") ))
 .sortByKey()                                      
 .reduceByKey((key, value) => key +"|" + value)
 .map(records => records._1 + "," + records._2)

finalOutputRDD.saveAsTextFile(deltaFileLocation)
```

my output is:

```
key,A~1|A~2|A~3|A~4|A~5|A~6|
```

Now I would like to pass a value dynamically (say 3) and I wanted the following output:

```
key,A~1|A~2|A~3
key,A~4|A~5|A~6
```

Comment: is `key` really constant (as in this example) or do you have different values of `key` which would have to be grouped separately?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to group by your keys, then generate new keys that are the key plus an integer, regroup by those keys, and finally discard the generated ints. Something like:

```
def reduceByKeyMaxN[K, V](rdd: RDD[(K, V)], n: Int, f: (V, V) => V): RDD[(K, V)] = {
  rdd
    .groupByKey()
    .flatMap { case (k, vs) =>
      vs.zipWithIndex.map{ case (v, i) => ((k, i / n), v) }
    }
    .reduceByKey(f)
    .map { case ((k, _), v) => (k, v) }
 }
```

Then you can replace the call to `reduceByKey` in your code with a call to this method.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, here's one approach:

1. Transform the dataset into a pair-RDD and apply `reduceByKey` to generate a RDD of (key, Seq(values))
2. `flatMap` the result dataset into grouped-lists of (key, value) using `grouped(n)`
3. Finally `reduce` each of the grouped lists into a RDD of (key, grouped-values-string)

Here's sample code with a slightly more generalized dataset:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("k1", "A", 1),
  ("k1", "A", 2),
  ("k1", "A", 3),
  ("k1", "A", 4),
  ("k1", "A", 5),
  ("k1", "A", 6),
  ("k2", "B", 1),
  ("k2", "B", 2),
  ("k2", "B", 3),
  ("k2", "B", 4)
))

val n = 3

rdd.map{ case (k, s, i) => (k, Seq(s + "~" + i)) }.
  reduceByKey( _ ++ _ ).
  flatMap{ case (k, vs) => vs.map(i => (k, i)).grouped(n) }.
  map( _.reduce( (acc, x) => (acc._1, (acc._2 + "|" + x._2)) ) ).
  collect
// res1: Array[(String, String)] =
//   Array((k1,A~1|A~2|A~3), (k1,A~4|A~5|A~6), (k2,B~1|B~2|B~3), (k2,B~4))
```